# AngularJS code works on Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, firefox

I got a simple code allowing a user to enter a youtube URL in an input box, and it displays the embed video. Everytime you enter a new url, it gets listed in a playlist below. If you click on an item on the playlist, the video switches to the new url.

You can copy paste this code, it works out of the box on Firefox, but in Chrome, **the click on the playlist** doesn't work.

I can't understand why as there is no error (and I'm NOT using the file:// protocol so this is not the problem, I use a server):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app='myApp'>
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>
            Player simple
        </title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

        <script>
        function onYouTubePlayerReady(){
            document.getElementById("ytplayer").playVideo();
        };

        angular.module('myApp', [])


        .factory("playlist", function($sce){

                var embedUrl = 'https://www.youtube.com/v/{{id}}?version=3&enablejsapi=1';

               var service = {};
               service.videos = [];
               var currentVideo;
               service.addVideo =  function(videoUrl){
                    var res = /youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([^&]+)/.exec(videoUrl);
                    var url = embedUrl.replace("{{id}}", res[1]);
                    service.videos.push(url);
                    if (service.videos.length == 1){
                        service.currentVideo = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(service.videos[0]);
                    }
                };

                service.playVideo = function(i){
                    console.log(i, service.videos[i])
                    service.currentVideo = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(service.videos[i]);
                }

                return service;
        })


        .controller('Controlleur', function($scope, playlist) {
            $scope.playlist = playlist;
        });

        </script>

    </head>

    <body  ng-controller="Controlleur">
        <div>
            <object width="640" height="360" ng-show="playlist.currentVideo" >
              <param name="movie" value="https://www.youtube.com/v/M7lc1UVf-VE?version=3"></param>
              <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
              <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always"></param>
              <embed ng-src="{{playlist.currentVideo}}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="360" id="ytplayer"></embed>
            </object>
        </div>
        <div>
            <form ng-submit="playlist.addVideo(playlist.addedVideo)">
                <p><input type="text" ng-model="playlist.addedVideo"><button>Add</button></p>
            </form>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="video in playlist.videos">
                    <a href="#" ng-click="playlist.playVideo($index)">{{video}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

    </body>

    </html>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Tested with [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gevmb6OlxWUryzayv1oB?p=preview) on FF and Chrome and it works on both of them. The only problem is when you add the same url twice, but you can fix this by adding a `track by $index` in your `ngRepeat`

Comment: Video adding works. The playlist switch doesn't. Does the playlist switch works for you ?

Comment: I don't know why you are getting down voted. I understood that clicking a playlist item was not working and I tested it and it is not working.

Comment: Thank you. It's pretty hard to be 204k rep and still be downvoted with no explanation.

Comment: Because rep indicates that posts made from said user are of high quality, right? /sarcasm

Comment: Did you see this? https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/339. Look at the comments.

Comment: @KevinB Because it indicates you gave a lot of your time to help the community and that you deserve at least the 2s it takes to justify a downvote. It's called being polite.

Comment: You should be polite regardless of rep level.

Comment: says the guy who came in here to post a useless comment

Comment: I tend to be kinder to people that spend a lot of time and energy to develop something I care about. I don't think that's a strange expectation to have the same in return.

Comment: @pasine: thanks, that's a very useful hint.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me on Chrome 46.0.2490.80 (64-bit) on MacOSX.

I used `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` to avoid the `file://` issue.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7jsFu.jpg

Comment: Video adding works. The playlist switch doesn't. Does the playlist switch works for you ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @pasine link, I found that indeed, it was caused by [this bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/339) and it can be solved by creating a directive :

```
.directive('embedSrc', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var current = element;
      scope.$watch(function() { return attrs.embedSrc; }, function () {
        var clone = element
                      .clone()
                      .attr('src', attrs.embedSrc);
        current.replaceWith(clone);
        current = clone;
      });
    }
  };
})
```

And using it in the embed:

```
      <embed embed-src="{{playlist.currentVideo}}" src="{{playlist.currentVideo}}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" allowScriptAccess="always" width="640" height="360" id="ytplayer"></embed>
```